# Price discount by age function

Tags: javascript, forms, html-select, equation

I currently have an assignment where I have to create a form for ordering stuff. e.g. a news paper. I’m almost finished, but there's a couple of things I really can’t figure.

I have a drop-down list for birth date; it’s set by day, month and year. I need to make it so that the total price is multiplied by 0.9 (10% off the price) when you are below 20 years old and ordering.

Here’s my code so far (with a stripped-down drop-down list):

```
<select name="select1" onClick="TheFunction()" size="1">
    <option>- Date -</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>

 </select>

 <select name=”select2” onClick="TheFunction()" size="1">
    <option>- Month -</option>
    <option value="1">Januari</option>
    <option value="2">Februari</option>
    <option value="3">Mars</option>
    <option value="4">April</option>
    <option value="5">Maj</option>
    <option value="6">Juni</option>
    <option value="7">Juli</option>
    <option value="8">Augusti</option>
    <option value="9">September</option>
    <option value="10">Oktober</option>
    <option value="11">November</option>
    <option value="12">December</option>

 </select>

 <select name=”select3” onClick="TheFunction()" size="1">
    <option>- Year -</option>
    <option value="2011">2011</option>
    <option value="2010">2010</option>
    <option value="2009">2009</option>
    <option value="2008">2008</option>
    <option value="2007">2007</option>
    <option value="2006">2006</option>
</select>
```

My thought is to make it so that ”year” is the option list that ”counts” e.g. if you’re born before 1993, you will pay full price, but if you’re born after you’ll get the discount. In this list we could say 2008 instead, since it’s shortened down.

If there’s any way to do this with an exact date, of course that would be better.

And here’s the script:

```
function TheFunction() {

    if (document.formular.select.select3.value >= 1993) {

        price = priceOne() + priceTwo() + priceThree()
        priceDiscount = (price)*(0.9);

    } else {

        price = priceOne() + priceTwo() + priceThree()
        priceDiscount = price;

    }

    document.formular.priset.value = priceDiscount

}
```

I’ve translated it from my native language (Swedish), I might have missed something.

So this is ”how” I think. But I’m looking for any solution to fix this, that isn’t way out of a beginner’s league.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below function instead of your function:

```
function TheFunction()

        {

             var d = new Date();
             if (d.getFullYear()-document.formular.select.select3.value >= 20){

              price = priceOne() + priceTwo() + priceThree()
              priceDiscount = (price)*(0.9);

              }

             else{
                    price = priceOne() + priceTwo() + priceThree()
            priceDiscount = price;

              }

              document.formular.priset.value = priceDiscount

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Form control values are text, so you should first convert them to numbers:

```
var yr = parseInt(document.formular.select.select3.value, 10);
```

but I suspect that you should remove the word 'select'. I haven't tested, but this won't AFAIK refer to all 'select' elements.

Comment: I thought about this too and I'm not sure wether to go for, however I'm in need of a working function, before I try that out. The double select, I mean. But you're referring to the months now?

Comment: I can add that "select.select3" didn't work, the "select3" is enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to give your select's ids; these can be the same as their name's.

```
var yr = document.getElementById('select3').value; // then 
yr = parseInt(yr, 10);
```

to convert to a number. Do this for each of the 3 selects, then you can convert these three numbers into a Date value:

```
var dob = new Date(yr, mth, dy);
```

and then perform the calculations you need.

[Mozilla - Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: By doing this, it would essentially be the same script as TechByte suggested, just that I "get" all of the lists and a more accurate calculation? The parseint, will that be the same for all of them? (I have to admit I'm not too familiar with it).

Comment: Yes, a more accurate calculation. Get all three parts, convert them to numbers using parseInt() then create a Date instance from them. Then you can use Date methods to calculate their age. Refer to the Mozilla link I provided; Date methods are listed further down.

Comment: I don't really get it to work. As soon as I input "(yr, mth, dy)", instead of leaving it empty, it starts to hassle. Eg. it works when only by year, but when I'm trying to get in the others, it either counts them as soon as I input any value, or literary nothing happens. Then I've done as you say, and used the script that TechByte provided.

Comment: The month-number would also need to be reduced by 1, as JS months start at Jan==0. Nevermind. Good luck.